# Zebra printer ZT610 doesn't print polish signs while ZTC 110 does

Tags: printing, utf-8, zebra-printers, zpl

I am trying to print polish signs with font Verdana  ( contains polish signs). The problem is that on the printer ZTC 110 code :

```
^XA 
^FS
^CWZ,E:VERDANAB.FNT^FS
^FT100,100^FH^FD żółć
^XZ
```

works perfectly fine and polish signs are printed , while on the new printer ZT610 polish letters are missing (font was downloaded properly with .TTF format). All I can see in a place of sign  is a blank space. When I m using zebra designer 2   polish letters are printed, they also are printed when I add command ^CI28 to the  code ( used ^FH^FD here and special utf 8 code for polish signs),

```
^XA 
^CI28
^FS
^CWZ,E:VERDANAB.TTF^FS
^FT100,100^FH^FD  _C5_BC_C3_B3_C5_82_C4_87_C5_B9  ( żółć // here is the blank space ) 
^XZ
```

but it  worked on previous printer without doing those things. Drivers were installed properly, fonts were installed properly, any ideas why is it happening?

Comment: I'd try using `^CFZ` to set the default font used in your printer after (along with?) `^CWZ…`. (By [the docs](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra_new_ia/en-us/manuals/printers/common/programming/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf#page=141&zoom=100,46,92), default is `^CFA`).

Comment: Unfortunatelly it didn't work. I checked with other fonts and font like arial ( which includes polish signs ) doesn't print those too. Only blank space is visible

Comment: The source of the issue was that I was trying to send UTF 8 through Zebra setup utilities and this program got problems with doing this. When I  opened file in Zebra utilities (created in Notepad ++) instead of typing commends everything worked properly.